# Extract the values of cells having formulas using openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to create an excel based automation using openpyxl module.
I am stuck with cell value extraction with a formula.
Lets say that I have 2 columns with data as shown below:

```
ws['A1'] = 3
ws['B1'] = 4
_ = ws.cell(row = 1, column=3, value='=SUM('+get_column_letter(1)+str(1)+':'+get_column_letter(2)+str(1)+')')
```

When I do "print(_.value)" it returns "=A1+B1" instead of "7". Is there any function that could possibly return the end value of the cells

Answer (score 1):

From the openpyxl documentation:

> openpyxl never evaluates formula

Comment: It does in the excel created by the code addition has happened

Answer (score 0):

Use the `data_only` property when initialising a workbook

`wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("...", data_only=True)`
`

Read more [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#read-an-existing-workbook)

Comment: Hi, thank you. Can I still embedd the formulas?

Comment: I think you'd have to reopen the workbook after you put down the formulas, because as stated below by Scott, openpyxl won't evaluate formulas by itself, it'll let excel do that job. Maybe try to write the formula without data_only, then reopen the wb with it set to True

Comment: Is there any hack other than that. I am trying to assign number format to the cell values. If cell value < 0.01 format as '0.00E+00'

Comment: Do the calculation in Python.  Or use a conditional format.